# Will My Entire File Be Sent To The Browser Or Only Part?

Tags: php, html, ajax

Say I have a 20kb file with some a switch statement like the following:

```
switch(action) {
    case 'thing1':
        //some HTML
        //5kb
    break;

    case 'thing2':
        //some more HTML
        //5kb
    break;

    case 'thing3':
        //the best HTML
        //5kb
    break;

    case 'thing4':
        //cat pics HTML
        //5kb
    break;

}
```

If I were to use an AJAX get call from a JS file to set action:

```
$.get(http://mywebsite.com/file.php?action=thing1, function(data) {});
```

Would the whole 20kb be sent to the browser, or only the 5kb of each set of HTML? I'm asking because I want to know if a webpage will be more efficient if you use multiple smaller files.

Comment: What happens when you test it?  When you make your AJAX call, use your browser's debugging tools to see the response from the server.  What does it contain?  What is its size?

Comment: No. Only the result (actual output) of that script will be sent.

Answer (score 4):

PHP source code is compiled and executed on the server, then the output of the program is sent to the client.